# Getting the TabItems generated with a template wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to create a variable number of tabs and then populate them via code. This XAML code correctly generates the tabs based on the collection Channels, which contains anonymous objects with only a Name property:

```
        <ItemsControl      
                Name="ChannelTabs"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Channels}"
                >

            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <UniformGrid Name="Channels" 
                            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                            Width="auto"
                                     Columns="2"
                            />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate.Resources>
                        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="18"/>
                            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" 
                                    Value="Center"/>
                        </Style>
                    </DataTemplate.Resources>

                    <TabItem 
                            Header="{Binding Path=Name}"
                            Tag="{Binding Path=Name}"
                            VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                            MinWidth="60"
                            Width="auto"
                            Margin="5,5,5,5"
                            Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"
                     >
                        <WrapPanel />
                    </TabItem>



                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>

        </ItemsControl>
```

Now, however, I need to populate those tabs, so I need to find them by Name. I'm trying this to find the TabItem whose Tag is equal to the string ch_name:

```
            TabItem tab = (Panel)ChannelTabs.Items.Items.Cast<TabItem>().First(ti => (string)ti.Tag == ch_name);
```

... but I get an error because I can't cast an anonymous object to a TabItem. Apparently the property Items does not contain, as I expected, the TabItem objects, but the anonymous objects. In other words, it contains the same as ItemsSource.

How can I access the actual TabItems created from the ItemsSource collection, and not the ItemsSource itself?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? The UI elements in the ItemTemplate of an ItemsControl should be "populated" with data from the elements of the ItemsSource collection.

Comment: I thought about it, but I didn't know how to do it, I want to put a series of custom controls on each tab, and I don't know how to bind each tab to a different ItemsSource (note that I don't know in advance th enumber of tabs). I guess there's a way to use a Dictinoary as ItemsSource, but it seemed easier to just do it in code.

Comment: These custom controls would typically be created by applying different DataTemplates via the ItemTemplateSelector of the ItemsControl.

Comment: You can however easily access the TabItems via the item containers of the ItemsControl. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

To get the tab item you need to have access to the `TabPanel` which is the container of the Tab Items.

To get access to the `TabPanel` you should handle the `Loaded` event and add the object to a variable you can later reference. In you tab control add the following setter

```
<TabControl.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabPanel}">
        <EventSetter Event="Loaded" Handler="TabPanel_Loaded"/>
    </Style>
</TabControl.Resources>
```

and in the event handler add it to a variable

```
TabPanel tabPanel;

private void TabPanel_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    tabPanel = sender as TabPanel;
}
```

and in your function you want to get the tab item you can do

```
TabItem tab = tabPanel.Children.OfType<TabItem>().First(ti => (string)ti.Tag == ch_name);
```

Comment: See Clemens' answer for the correct way to obtain item containers.

Comment: Also, he is not using the TabControl. He's using the ItemsControl. This means your solution is not working at all. His Panel is a UniformGrid that uses ContentPresenter as container.

Comment: Even if the question would be about a TabControl it would make no sense at all to directly access the TabPanel that is used as ItemsPanel. You would still use the ItemContainerGenerator.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily access the TabItem via the item container element of the ItemsControl.

The item container is a ContentPresenter that is available via the `ItemContainerGenerator` and its `ContainerFromItem` or `ContainerFromIndex` method:

```
var item = Channels[0]; // for example
var container = (ContentPresenter)ChannelTabs.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item);
```

The TabItem is the first child of the container:

```
var tabItem = (TabItem)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(container, 0);
```